# Pandas group by time of day from Datetime multi-index level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a dataframe with a multi-index that contains a level named `datetime` which is a `DatetimeIndex`. I want to group my data by the time of day. Is it idiomatic to do so via

```
df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('datetime').time).something()
```

? I'm asking because I'm not a fan of the `.get_level_values('datetime')` part of this. In particular: If `datetime` was not part of the index, I could more easily write

```
df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.time).something()
```

It was my impression that the point of treating columns as indices was to make these kind of operations more straightforward, so I'm surprised the opposite is the case here.

**EDIT**:
I realized that if I could easily split my `datetime` level into a `date` level and a `time` level, I could do

```
# change df.index to have levels [date, time, x, y, z] instead of [datetime, x, y, z]
df.groupby(level='time').something()
```

This looks pretty optimally succinct, so if the splitting can be done elegantly, that would also answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it idiomatic to do so via

```
df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values('datetime').time).median()
```

> ?

I think yes, if want attribute of `MultiIndex` level, like here [`DatetimeIndex.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.time.html) with level name.

You can also use select level by position - here first level:

```
df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values(0).time).median()
```

Your edit solution should be simplify:

```
df.groupby(level='time').median()
df.groupby(level=1).median()
#some functions like sum, mean, median
df.median(level=1)
```

EDIT:

If possible, simpliest is split values to date and times and then create `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'datetime': pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-05 15:00:00'] * 3 + ['2000-01-06'] * 3),
         'x':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'y':[7] * 6,
         'z':[1,3] * 3,
         'col':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})

df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.time

df = df.set_index(['date','time','x','y','z']).drop('datetime', axis=1)
print (df)
                           col
date       time     x y z     
2000-01-05 15:00:00 4 7 1    5
                    5 7 3    3
                    4 7 1    6
2000-01-06 00:00:00 5 7 3    9
                        1    2
                    4 7 3    4
```

If input data has already `datetimeindex` in `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'datetime': pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-05 15:00:00'] * 3 + ['2000-01-06'] * 3),
         'x':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'y':[7] * 6,
         'z':[1,3] * 3,
         'col':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
}).set_index(['datetime','x','y','z'])

print (df1)
                           col
datetime            x y z     
2000-01-05 15:00:00 4 7 1    5
                    5 7 3    3
                    4 7 1    6
2000-01-06 00:00:00 5 7 3    9
                        1    2
                    4 7 3    4

names = ['date','time','x','y','z']
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(d.date(), d.time(),a,b,c) 
                                       for d,a,b,c in df1.index], names=names)
print (df1)
                           col
date       time     x y z     
2000-01-05 15:00:00 4 7 1    5
                    5 7 3    3
                    4 7 1    6
2000-01-06 00:00:00 5 7 3    9
                        1    2
                    4 7 3    4
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the first bit of the EDIT solution?

Comment: @Bananach - In your code is created MultiIndex? E.g. by `set_index` ? Or parameter `index_col` in `read_csv` ?

Comment: It's from external code. Definitely helpful to have the overview given in your answer.